# 同じ一日 - Is this a common phrase?

Tags: phrases

I saw 同じ一日 from an example sentence: 今日はいつもと同じ一日だった。

Is this phrase commonly used? Is it similar to 今日も一日?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 同じ is a 形容動詞 (called na-adjective in English) that modifies 一日 (a day). I wouldn't call 同じ一日 a set phrase like 今日も一日. It is just a noun phrase composed of an adjective and a noun. 同じ, when used before a noun that it modifies, often occurs without な.

For example, 彼と同じ学校だ means "the same school as the one he attends"

> 今日はいつもと同じ一日だった。

Just means

> Today was just another day, same as usual.